# Using macros to format charts in excel

Tags: excel, vba, graph, charts

I'm trying to create a macro that will format charts in Excel so that all of my charts have the same formatting, but different data. Usually I would just paste the formatting, but these charts were made using a plugin and they do not appear to be compatible with 'paste formats'. Each chart is in a different worksheet along with the chart data.

My charts have 3 series. Each series has a particular format e.g. 
series 1: circular marker, size-3pt, no marker line, green fill. 
series 2: circular marker, size-3pt, black marker line, yellow fill. 
series 3: circular marker, size-3pt, no marker line, red fill.

Also, the charts need to be a specific size for presentation (no sure exact sizes yet, but presumably that should be easy to edit).

These are the only parameters that I need to change from the default in order to get the charts to look how I want them. Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you're on Excel 2010 then I think the macro recording of chart actions is much improved over 2007, so you could try recording a macro and start from there.

Comment: i would rather warn you - had my own fun with chart formatting, and under 2007 it is a little nightmare, if you really get into details: macro recorder does not work; often it's not that clear where to find a specific setting; and when I recall right, sometime there even just weren't some option available under VBA - just via the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Chart formatting can be done fairly easily with VBA:

```
Dim chChart as chart
set chChart = Thisworkbook.Sheet("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart1").Chart
With chChart
    seriescollection(1).Markerforegroundcolor = rgb(255,255,255)
    seriescollection(1).Markerbackgroundcolor = rgb(255,255,255)
    seriescollection(1).interior.color = rgb(255,255,255)
End With
```

The above code should give you an idea of how to write the macro, substituting the correct sheet and chart names. Ideally you would also use some loops to loop through you charts and series within the charts

```
For each chart in Thisworkbook.Sheet("Sheet1").ChartObjects
For each series in chChart.seriescollection
```

To get the exact values you want to change I would suggest either recording a macro of you making the changes manually or using the Editor Object Browser (F2 in the VBA Editor) to find the likely values.